# How to convert Python string to a list of dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following string in Python:

```
str1 = "{1:11,2:22},{1:33,2:44}"
str1
```

Output:

```
'{1:11,2:22},{1:33,2:44}'
```

How can I convert str1 to a list of dicts so that the result will look like the following:

```
[{1:11,2:22},{1:33,2:44}]
```

... so that `my_dict[0]` will return

```
{1:11,2:22}
```

and the type of `my_dict[0]` will also be a Python dict (and not a string)?

Comment: Why do you call the variable `my_dict` when it's a list, not a dictionary?

Comment: Add `[` and `]` around the string, then use `ast.literal_eval()`.

Comment: Or `literal_eval` first and convert the tuple into a list afterwards (if you really care about the difference).